# For Loop in Oracle / Toad

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I am new to Oracle and PL/SQL and am trying to do the following.

I am returning the column names from a table name that is stored in a variable

```
variable v_table varchar2(100)
begin
select 'mytable' into :v_table from dual;
end;

select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = :v_table
```

This returns a rowset

```
column_name
colname1
colname2
colname3
```

I would like to loop through the returned rowset and get some stats for each column.

```
select count distinct(colname1), min(colname1), max(colname1)
from :v_table
group by min(colname1), max(colname1)
```

However I cannot figure out how to loop through this rowset.

Comment: If you gather statistics on the tables using DBMS_Stats, then you can select this data directly from the data dictionary. In fact, it may already be there.

Comment: Thanks for the response @davidAldridge. It looks like I don't have the privileges to execute these procedures.

Comment: It may be that the statistics are being gathered automatically anyway.

Answer (score 0):

By using below you can display column names of a table and append your sql query as per your requirement...

```
    declare
         v_table varchar2(100):='TABLE_NAME';
         TYPE NT_VAR1 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
         TYP_NT NT_VAR1;
        begin
        select column_name BULK COLLECT INTO TYP_NT from all_tab_columns where table_name =v_table
        order by column_id;
        FOR I IN 1..TYP_NT.COUNT
        LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COLUMN '||I||': '||TYP_NT(I));
        END LOOP;
        end;
```

**Note**:  You should run select query dynamically means with the use of execute immediate why because you are passing table_name at run time.

**Edit**
   After editing your query in for loop it will look like below.

```
 declare
         v_table varchar2(100):='TABLE_NAME';
         TYPE NT_VAR1 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
         TYP_NT NT_VAR1;
         var2 varchar2(2000);
         var3 varchar2(2000);
        begin
        select column_name BULK COLLECT INTO TYP_NT from all_tab_columns where table_name =v_table
        order by column_id;
        FOR I IN 1..TYP_NT.COUNT
        LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COLUMN '||I||': '||TYP_NT(I));
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT to_char(min('||TYP_NT(I)||')),to_char(max('||TYP_NT(I)||')) from '||v_table into var2,var3;
        dbms_output.put_line(var2||' '||var3);
        END LOOP;
        end;
```

Note: Find the max data length of a column present in your table and assign same data type to var2 and var3 variables.

Comment: Thanks @Tarun. Please ignore the last edit of this comment. It works nicely and I see the results in the DBMS Output window.

Comment: Yes you can see it, Which tool you are using?

Comment: I think you are using toad Are you able to see data grid window?

Comment: if u not able to  see the DBMS_OUTPUT tab at the bottom (alongside where you see your query results), right click on one of the tabs and select DBMS_OUTPUT.  You can toggle on Output On/Off with the button displayed on that tab.

Comment: now that I see the output, I am trying to incorporate my select logic into the loop. however, it seems that my v_table variable is not being passed: `code`  
select column_name BULK COLLECT INTO TYP_NT from all_tab_columns where table_name =v_table
        order by column_id;
        FOR I IN 1..TYP_NT.COUNT
        LOOP
                 select MIN(TYP_NT(I)), MAX(TYP_NT(I)) from v_table;
        END LOOP;
        end; `code`